# Fetching relation data from multiple related tables

Tags: mysql, select, join, relational

I'm working on a database structure for a small game, this game utilizes 'kits' as in armor sets. Currently I have 4 tables: "kit", "kit_armor", "kit_item" and "kit_item_enchantment".
The "kit" tables holds the id of the kit and it's name, the "kit_armor" tables holds the armor for a kit, the "kit_item" table holds the items which the "kit_armor" columns can point to and the "kit_item_enchantment" table holds additional enchantment data for the specific items.

Now I've been experimenting with queries as well as we searching stack-overflow and the reset of the internet to write a query which will get all kit information from the database, without any results, unfortunately.

This is the table structure:

```
mysql> describe kit;
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| kit_id   | int(4) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| kit_name | varchar(32)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe kit_armor;
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| kit_id     | int(4) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| helmet     | int(4) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| chestplate | int(4) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| leggings   | int(4) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| boots      | int(4) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe kit_item;
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(4) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_id    | int(4) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| stack_size | int(4) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe kit_item_enchantment;
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| item_id        | int(4) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| enchantment_id | int(4) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| tier           | int(4) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And referenced columns:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------
| TABLE_NAME                | COLUMN_NAME        | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME |
+---------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------
| kit_armor                 | kit_id             | kit                   | kit_id                 |
| kit_armor                 | helmet             | kit_item              | id                     |
| kit_armor                 | chestplate         | kit_item              | id                     |
| kit_armor                 | leggings           | kit_item              | id                     |
| kit_armor                 | boots              | kit_item              | id                     |
| kit_item_enchantment      | item_id            | kit_item              | id                     |
```

My question is what would be the best way to obtain all the kit information and whether it is possible to do so in a single query (JOINs?) or do I have to split it up into multiple queries?

It would help me alot, I've been struggling with this issue since yesterday, meanwhile I've done a lot of research on the best way to select relation data from databases and I've only came across very complex guides and queries which are incredibly confusing.

Thanks in advance,

Jonas

Comment: it seems u have connection between all these tables and so yes you can join 3 tables together and its the performance wise best way to get result. yes you can write single query for this. without your expected result can't say anything....

Comment: @Tilt Could you perhaps point me in the correct direction query wise? I've been playing with different join and multiple select queries and I'm unable to get the data out in a fashion where I can parse it correctly. E.g. I'd like to have the kit_item values for helmet, chestplate, leggings and boots and they should be NULL of the value of NULL (so I know that this kit doesn't need a helmet for example).